# PDO JOIN LEFT - fetch result - no result

Tags: php, pdo, left-join

I have 2 tables in 1 database. The result shall have all values, which are **NOT** in table 2. The request like this works fine, but is really slow. I would like to change to LEFT JOIN

```
$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM spotify WHERE 
pos1 > '0' AND pos1 <= '100' 
AND (land = 'GLOBAL' OR land = 'DE') 
AND link_id NOT IN (SELECT URL FROM spotify_blacklist) ORDER BY song ASC";
```

This is what i have so far - it would be great to get your help!

```
$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM spotify 
WHERE pos1 > '0' AND pos1 <= '100' 
AND (land = 'GLOBAL' OR land = 'DE') LEFT JOIN spotify_blacklist  
ON (spotify.link_id != spotify_blacklist.URL) 
WHERE spotify_blacklist.URL IS NULL";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($abfrage);
$stmt->execute();
```

Can someone help me on this? 
PS. link_id & URL are URL´s.

Comment: is pos1 integer column?

Comment: It is a decimal (3,0) value

Comment: You need to put the `JOIN ... ON ...` before the conditions.

Comment: I tried it, but still no luck

Comment: Even if i do it like this - i don´t get a result `$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM spotify LEFT JOIN spotify_blacklist  ON (spotify.link_id = spotify_blacklist.URL) WHERE spotify_blacklist.URL IS NULL";`

Comment: I found the mistake - in table 2 were duplicate entries.